# Finding the number of derivatives for series problems

Tags: calculus, derivatives, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I have the following problem:

> How smooth are the following functions? That is, how many derivatives
>   can you guarantee them to have?
>
> $$a)\;\;\;\;\; f(\theta)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in\theta}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1}$$
>   $$b)\;\;\;\;\; f(\theta)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n\theta}{2^n}$$
>   $$c)\;\;\;\;\; f(\theta)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos 2^n\theta}{2^n}$$

How should I approach this problem? Do I need to check whether the derivatives of the series are convergent or not perhaps?

The answers should be (from my book):

> $$a)\;\;\;\;\;12$$ $$b)\;\;\;\;\;\infty$$ $$c)\;\;\;\;\;0$$

Comment: Yup.  Do termwise differentiation and test whether the series converges.

Comment: Hi @chriseur =) Any hints on how to prove that $a)$ converges for 12 first derivatives, but not for the 13th derivative? =) I think I just need to prove that $\sum \frac{n^{12}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1}$ is convergent, but $\sum \frac{n^{13}}{n^{13.2}+2n^6-1}$ isn't. How should I do this? =)